# How to use cookies in python with other platform

Tags: python, cookies

My python app lets people upload files on a Third-party platform.

They need to ask my server for a token for the platform to verify

It looks like:

[image]

when people upload files they post to the platform

```
<form method="post" action="http://upload.qiniu.com/"
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="key" type="hidden" value="<resource_key>">
  <input name="x:<custom_name>" type="hidden" value="<custom_value>">
  <input name="token" type="hidden" value="<upload_token>">
  <input name="file" type="file" />
  <input name="crc32" type="hidden" />
  <input name="accept" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

I wonder if it's ok to ask for the token each time someone tries to upload files, or just let people get the token when they login, set the token into the cookie and make its lifetime as long as the cookie's?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal practice to store client access tokens as cookies for returning users.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3401546/4013571) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161266/how-to-securely-store-access-token-and-secret-in-android) SO post also back this idea up.

Comment: Another way is  each time when someone tries to upload files,use ajax to get token from the server.Which way is better?Thanks